# YouTube API for objective C has a "?" (question mark) in the name "videoId?:" for a GTLYouTubeResourceId

Tags: youtube-api

I really believe that this worked at some point but it is dropping an exception and crashing when it gets to here:

```
GTLYouTubeResourceId *thisVideo = item.identifier;
NSString *myVidId = thisVideo.videoId;
```

here is the error:

```
2012-12-17 10:13:02.494 STATS[21427:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GTLYouTubeVideo videoId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc471500'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e15012 0x16b2e7e 0x1ea04bd 0x1e04bbc 0x1e0494e 0x6e11 0x4ae5a 0x16c66b0 0xde7035 0x1d98f3f 0x1d9896f 0x1dbb734 0x1dbaf44 0x1dbae1b 0x276f7e3 0x276f668 0x2ee65c 0x278d 0x26b5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

the JSON that comes back from the API is formatted with a ? in the Video id title

```
2012-12-17 10:20:46.476 STATS[21630:11603]      *****  YOUTUBe thisVideo GTLYouTubeVideo 0x8267fe0: {kind:"youtube#video" videoId?:"AAAAAAAA"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by doing something like this.  Apparently, the JSON string returned has videoId in there.

NSString *myVidId = [thisVideo.JSON objectForKey:@"videoId"];

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem about an hour after you! It looks like they have forgotten to map videoId to a property. If you change thisVideo to be of class GTLYouTubeVideo, like this:

```
GTLYouTubeVideo *thisVideo = (GTLYouTubeVideo *)item.identifier;
```

Then go to the GTLYouTube.m file and change @"id", @"identifier" to be @"videoId", @"identifier" it will work. This probably isn't the official way, but they haven't provided any documentation on integrating YouTube into an app so this will have to do!

Hope it helps

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: This worked, but there you actually want to add a line instead of replace .... there are other results that will then break if you do not have the id to identifier mapped so there should be three mapped lines:    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"etag", @"ETag",
     @"videoId",@"videoId",
     @"id",@"identifier",
      nil];